# proper way to return 1 value with jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I need to query DB for a max value of 1 column 
I'm trying to do it this sway

```
    public static long getLastJobSeqNum(){

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT max(JOBIQ) as JOBIQ FROM JOBS_RUN_STAT", long.class);
}
```

and I'm getting a nullpointer error even I know that there is 1 row on db; seems like it's not a save way to query for a max value

how to make it properly ?

Comment: can you show the error message

Comment: You call it as a static method? Are you injecting the jdbcTemplate? Can you show the constructor/fields of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Spring tries to unbox into a long primitive. Therefore if you have no elements the `JOBIQ` will be null as well. The null `Long` initially created cannot be unboxed without causing a null pointer. You might use `Long.class` as a second parameter and wrap the whole method call in an `Optional.ofNullable(<jdbcCall>).orElse(<fallbackvalue>)`

Comment: i tried this way ..orElse(0) and it works good. can you tell me if i'm getting it right - first part is going to connect to the db and get the value and second part is there only for the case if that value is null on db ?

Comment: The Optional API is a (relatively) new approach for handling null values. It wraps the original value. The orElse is a mapping method which checks the value inside and if it's null then it returns the value passed to the orElse method instead of the null. The db connection is done by jdbcTemplate call still.